# How to get current product ids from this saveEntityFinish() function and insert to table

Tags: magento2

I want to insert **product_id** during product csv import from the below saveEntityFinish() function, just like how i am inserting 'sku'.

My table currently has:

**sku** column.

I want to add **product_id column** ans get the current products id from the function and insert.

```
public function getEntityTypeCode()
{
    return 'my_import';  
}

protected function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData, $table)
{
    if ($entityData) {
        $tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName($table);
        $entityIn = [];
        foreach ($entityData as $id => $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $entityIn[] = $row;
                }
        }
        if ($entityIn) {
            $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $entityIn,[
            self::SKU
        ]);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```